# Can anyone suggest me about timezone used by aws-ec2 instance and rds. Can we change this time zone?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using AWS-RDS for the database. AWS-EC2 instance for my application. When I am trying to save date using my application I used IST time zone. But when value inserted into the database then it will show me UTC time zone. Can we change this time zone?

I am trying to save user-defined date using the angular application from the front end and I used spring boot as back end. I use column data type as date and time zone as IST. When I am running this my application then this will work correctly. But when I am trying to run the application using AWS then this will use UTC time zone. Because of this UTC, it will use the previous day's date.

If I am using IST time zone at local, Then Can I use this time zone on AWS? If yes then how can I use this? If no then recommend me which timezone is work properly on local as well as on AWS? I want an exact date which is selected by my client using the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone cannot be modified once you select it while creating new RDS for sql server instance. If you want to then you have to create a new instance.

Use the 'Select your Time Zone' dropdown in the AWS Management Console to do so while creating a new instance.

Or you can try to convert present IST time into utc while storing in database and convert it back again into IST when required.